How to create a dynamic Stepper (timeline) in Js/jquery
I am looking for a solution to create a dynamic stepper. In the Snippet, when i select Heudebouville and then feedbackDo, all the checkboxes between should be checked, that's good for the moment, but if i want to deselect one of the checkboxes between (for example : Babille) it should be deselect (checked=false without changing the classNames), but it's not the case here.
in the example below, i checked the first checkbox and another one, the checkboxes between are checked (it's good) but when i try to deselect them ( Post a contest or Provide feedback) they still checked.
Click here to see the Gif
The question is, why i cannot deselect a checkbox between the 1st and last one (example Provide (n°6a) 6 €) ? and how to allow this ?
I  hope it's clear Here my code :


// Switch cites
$("#fluxLibreSwitchCity").click(function() {
  var fromCity = $(".FluxLibreStep2__From .FluxLibreStep2__City");
  var toCity = $(".FluxLibreStep2__To .FluxLibreStep2__City");

  // Inverse  cities
  var tempCity = fromCity.text();
  fromCity.text(toCity.text());
  toCity.text(tempCity);

  // Inverse passages
  var passages = $(".StepProgress > li");
  var reversedPassages = passages.toArray().reverse();
  $(".StepProgress").html(reversedPassages);
  $(".StepProgress").toggleClass("inverse");
  redrawSteps();
  CalculatePrice();
});

// Road
// Calculate prices
const CalculatePrice = () => {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      var price = parseFloat(
        $(this).siblings("label").find(".infoORprice").text().trim()
      );
      totalPrice += price;
    });
    $("#totalPrice").text(totalPrice.toFixed(2) + " €");
  });
};
CalculatePrice();

// order checkbox
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(
  '.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]'
);

checkboxes.forEach((checkbox, index) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
    redrawSteps();
  });
});
const redrawSteps = () => {
  const bluePath = document.querySelectorAll(".StepProgress-item");
  bluePath.forEach((li) => li.classList.remove("is-active"));

  const checked = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked'
  );

  if (checked.length > 1) {
    const first = checked[0].closest("li");
    const last = checked[checked.length - 1].closest("li");
    let started = false;
    let finished = false;

    bluePath.forEach((li) => {
      if (li === first) {
        started = true;
      } else if (li === last) {
        finished = true;
      }

      if (started && !finished) {
        const checkbox = li.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
        li.classList.add("is-active");
        if (checkbox && !li.classList.contains("subItem")) {
          checkbox.checked = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  var allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".StepProgress-item");
  allItems.forEach(function(item) {
    var checkbox = item.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    if (checkbox && checkbox.checked) {
      item.classList.add("selected");
    } else {
      item.classList.remove("selected");
    }
  });
};
.StepProgress {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.StepProgress:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 90px);
  border-left: 4px solid gray;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.StepProgress__FromToCity {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
  margin-left: -6px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.StepProgress__FromToCity:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 18 18' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M15 7.5c0 4.5-6 9-6 9s-6-4.5-6-9a6 6 0 1 1 12 0' stroke='%23787878' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3Cpath d='M9 9.75a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 0-4.5 2.25 2.25 0 0 0 0 4.5' stroke='%23787878' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.StepProgress__FromToCity:last-child {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.StepProgress-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  height: 100px;
}

.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  left: -8px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 17px -4px gray;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
}

.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e0f8ff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.StepProgress-item__subItemPassageNum {
  display: contents;
}

.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage span {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage .infoORprice {
  color: gray;
}

.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.6);
  align-self: baseline;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}

.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage .icon::before {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.StepProgress-item.selected>* {
  z-index: 1;
}

.StepProgress-item.selected:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #f4f4f499;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem.selected>* {
  z-index: 1;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem.selected:after {
  content: "";
  left: -40px;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 17px -4px gray;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage:before {
  background-color: blue;
  left: -67px;
  width: 30px;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem .StepProgress-item__InfoPassage {
  position: relative;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem .StepProgress-item__InfoPassage:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -70px;
  top: 16px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 4px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: gray0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem.is-active {
  position: relative;
}

.StepProgress-item.subItem.is-active:before {
  content: "";
  left: -40px;
  top: 14px;
  height: 100%;
}

.StepProgress-item.not-active * {
  color: #787878;
}

.StepProgress-item.not-active input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.StepProgress-item.not-active .StepProgress-item__InfoPassage+span {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.StepProgress-item:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.StepProgress-item.is-active:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  width: 4px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="FluxLibreStep2" id="step2">
  <button class="FluxLibre__IconBackStep" id="returnToPreviousStep"></button>

  <div class="FluxLibreStep2__top">


    <div class="FluxLibreStep2__FromTo">
      <div class="FluxLibreStep2__From">
        <span>De</span>
        <div class="FluxLibreStep2__City">
          Paris </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="FluxLibre__IconSwitch" id="fluxLibreSwitchCity"></button>
      <div class="FluxLibreStep2__To">
        <span>Vers</span>
        <div class="FluxLibreStep2__City">
          Caen</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="FluxLibreStep2__Road">
    <ul class="StepProgress list-inline">
      <li class="StepProgress__FromToCity">
        Paris
      </li>
      <li class="StepProgress-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="point1" name="passage" value="point1">
        <label for="point1" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Heudebouville
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                12 €</span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A10</span>
                                        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="StepProgress-item subItem">
        <input type="checkbox" id="point2" name="passage" value="point2">
        <label for="point2" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Montreuil
                                            <span class="StepProgress-item__subItemPassageNum">(n°6a)</span>
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                12 €</span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconSousPassage  }}" aria-hidden="true">A11</span>
                                        </label>
      </li>

      <li class="StepProgress-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="point4" name="passage" value="point4">
        <label for="point4" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Babille
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                12 €</span>

                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A12</span>
                                        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="StepProgress-item subItem not-active">
        <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" id="point5" name="passage" value="point5">
        <label for="point5" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Handover
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                Ouverture du portic flux libre le 25/12/2024
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconSousPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A13</span>
                                        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="StepProgress-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="point6" name="passage" value="point6">
        <label for="point6" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Provide
                                            <span class="StepProgress-item__subItem-PassageNum">
                                                (n°6a)
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                6 €
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A51</label>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="StepProgress-item subItem">
        <input type="checkbox" id="point7" name="passage" value="point7">
        <label for="point7" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                             feedbackDo
                                            <span class="StepProgress-item__subItem-PassageNum">
                                                (n°6a)
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                6 €
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A51</label>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="StepProgress__FromToCity">
        Caen
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Selected option:
    <span id="selectedOption"></span>
  </p>

  <div class="FluxLibreStep2__TotalPrice">
    <p>{{ fluxLibreTotalPrice}}
    </p>
    <span id="totalPrice">0</span>
  </div>
</section>




The if (checkbox && !li.classList.contains("subItem")) { checkbox.checked = true; } appears to be what is preventing you from de-selecting the checkboxes - because this immediately sets it checked again.

@CBroe, if i remove this if and i select both of checkboxes, the other ones between are not checked

I didn't say removing this will magically fix it, I merely pointed out what is causing the mentioned issue, to give you are starting point.
